# Is it possible to track the very exact location of my website user using PHP, Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I Want to get the exact location of the user who visited my website how to do that?

In this one code is for tracking the ip of a user and fetch the longitude and latitude and saving it to database. and in 2nd code i am showing the data on the map pointer. but the problem is that the latitude and longitude fetched does not pin point or say do not provide accurate point on the map it shows somewhat 200 to 300 meters or sometimes 500 meters away from the location.

Comment: Try to use [google analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/). Understand how it works and make your API.

Comment: Short answer, you can't. My IP has no relationship at all to where I am and never will.

Comment: _“it shows somewhat 200 to 300 meters or sometimes 500 meters away from the location”_ - based on the IP address? Then I would call that a surprisingly accurate result already.

Comment: Short of insisting your users all implant satellite tracking chips into their arms and use custom hardware to automatically relay that information back to your server, you're never going to be certain of where they are...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No

Slightly longer answer: No, a IP address isn't like a house address, it has no correlation to a physical location, we can only somewhat guess where a user is by their IP address (don't ask me how it works), and that's only if the user isn't using something like a proxy or a VPN

Comment: So there is no way of getting the user exact pin point location in javascript or php or ajax or jquery.

Comment: Then can u tell me how this online delivery system for example swiggy or zomato do there tracking system with which system??\

Comment: You asked about getting it from IP, that's impossible. However you can use the Geolocation API to get the exact location (with the users consent only). It's the thing that pops up when you open maps, something like "www.google.com wants to know your location"